# Header errors during transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I am getting header errors in transcoded files of ffmpeg.

Code used: `ffmpeg -nostdin -ss 00:01:00.000 -t 00:02:00.000 -i /media/INPUTFILE1 -ss 00:03:00.001 -t 00:02:00.000 -i /media/INPUTFILE2 "[0:v:0] [1:v:0] concat=n=2:v=1[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -bf 3 -keyint_min 50 -sc_threshold 0 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -movflags frag_keyframe -b:v:0 500k -minrate 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 100k -muxrate 500k -s:v:0 512x384 -f ismv -threads 4 /media/SD_4X3_500K_V6.ismv`

What could be the cause of the issue?

Attached error screen shot.

[image: Error]

Comment: Which analyzer is this?

Comment: @Gyan Vega H264, it's right there in the middle :) They say it's capable of analyzing Smooth.

Comment: Yes it is vega analyzer

Comment: Didn't think to look there :) If you save as MP4, does it give the same errors?

Comment: And do they actually impact the playback because in the screen-shot they look like warnings and not errors?

Comment: The very first error give me pause. It says, "*unexpected Box type pasp found in avc1*". Both pasp and clap are optional boxes which can be included in the video tag (here `avc1`), as per 12.1.4 of 14496-12. The uuid boxes in each fragment header are ISML manifests containing metadata and codec configuration. That's a MS extension so it won't validate against ISO 14496. Not sure there's anything to see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not errors. Those boxes are fine. The analyzer just doesn’t know how to parse them. The players that need them know how to parse them.